# Creating a method that takes in one string Argument, and searches to see if its in a list

Tags: c#, methods

How do I create a method that takes in a string, and checks to see if that string is part of a list of strings.   Sorry for the poor wording, but my code will makes sense of what I'm trying to do.

```
public static string CuswAnswer(string MyStr1)
    {


        if (MyStr1 == "$22 $1008" || "$22 $1009" || "$22 $102A" || "$22 $2001" || "$22 $2002" || "$22 $2003" || "$22 $2008" || "$22 $2009" || "$22 $200A" || "$22 $200B" || "$22 $200C" || "$22 $200F" || "$22 $2010" || "$22 $2024" || "$22 $292E" || "$22 $F100" || "$22 $F10B" || "$22 $F112" || "$22 $F122" || "$22 $F132" || "$22 $F158" || "$22 $F180" || "$22 $F181" || "$22 $F182" || "$22 $F184" || "$22 $F185" || "$22 $F186" || "$22 $F187" || "$22 $F18C" || "$22 $F190" || "$22 $F192" || "$22 $F193" || "$22 $F194" || "$22 $F195" || "$22 $F196" || "$22 $F1A0" || "$22 $F1A1" || "$22 $F1A4" || "$22 $F1A5")
        {
            string Answer = "Yes";
            return Answer;

        }
        else
        {
            String Answer = "No";
            return Answer;
        }


    }
```

This works with just one.  Once I put in the ||'s it says it can't do it.

Comment: I see no one has told you why what you're doing *doesn't* work... Instead of `MyStr1 == "first" || "second"`, you should be using `MyStr1 == "first" || MyStr1 == "second"`. The expression before the `||` is evaluated, and if false, the next one will be evaluated. If that next expression is just a string (`"$22 $102A"`), that will not evaluate to true or false since it's *just a string*. That being said, Gabe's answer below is an appropriate way to accomplish your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test it by either `MyStr1 == "$22 $1008" || MyStr1 == "$22 $1009" || ...`, or you can rather put all possible values in a List, and then simply use `if(myList.Contains(MyStr1))`.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend storing strings in a collection.

```
private List<string> stringCollection = new List<string> { "string1", "string2", "string3" };

private string check(string input){
    if (stringCollection.Contains (input))
        return "Yes";
    else
        return "No";
}
```

**How it works:**

The list is a collection of objects. The type of the object is specified
between those "<" , ">" symbols. In this case <
**string>**

The object type indicates
what the collection holds. In this case it holds some strings.

We directly put some values into the collection (upon initialization) by using the
brackets. You can also add new items by using the **Add** method:

```
stringCollection.Add("string2014");
```

You can find more useful methods and a more detailed explanation on the link below.

**Usage:**

check("string1"); // returns "Yes"

check("string4"); // returns "No"

**Notes:**

[Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You should really give a explanation to.